# How to make custom camera lens effects in ios

Tags: ios, camera, effect

I am not an ios developer but my client wants me to make an iphone app like 
    https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trippy-booth-amazing-filterswarps/id448037560?mt=8
I have seen some custom library like 
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage
but do not find any camera lens customization example.
any kind of suggestions would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: ![sample effects] (https://s3.mzstatic.com/r30/Purple/v4/2c/35/d5/2c35d585-e7cd-cd31-3a7b-5dd923e4fe34/screen1136x1136.jpeg)

Comment: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage will solve my problem.
I have found some camera filter which i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through some custom shader written in OpenGL(or metal just for iOS), then you can apply your shader to do interesting stuff like the image in above link.

I suggest you take a look at how to use the OpenGL framework in iOS.
Basically the flow would like:
Use whatever framework to capture(even in real time) a image.
Use some framework to modify the image. (The magic occur here) 
Use another stuff to present the image.

You should learn how to obtain a OpenGL context, draw a image on it, write a custom shader, apply the shader, get the output, to "distort the image". For real, the hardest part is how to create that "effect" in your mind by describing it using a formula.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,Is it possible to implement without using OpenGl or some opensource library that will help me to achieve my goal

Comment: If you just want to apply some simple filter and transform effect, use CoreImage's CIFilter and CIDetector can do it well. But if you want to make your own effect, even in CoreImage, you still have to provide a "kernel", basically it's a shader.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to the photoshop mesh warp (Edit->Transform->Warp).  Basically you treat your image as a texture and then you render it on to a mesh (Bezier Patch) that is a grid that has been distorted into bezier curves, but you leave the texture coordinates as if it was still a grid.  This has the effect of "pulling" the image towards the nodes of the patch.  You can use OpenGL (GL_PATCHES) for this; I imagine metal or sceneKit might work as well.

I can't tell from the screen shots but its possible that the examples you reference are actually placing their mesh based on facial recognition.  CoreImage has [basic facial recognition](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html) to give youth out and eye positions which you could use to control some of the nodes in your mesh.

Comment: Thanks for responding Josh,
will you please give me a step by step tutorial or some framework i should start with